# SDL read pixels from texture

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, pixel, sdl-2

I want to read pixels from a texture using SDL2 library.
I know that it's not possible to directly read a pixel from a texture, but you can use the following function:

```
int SDL_RenderReadPixels(SDL_Renderer*   renderer,
                     const SDL_Rect* rect,
                     Uint32          format,
                     void*           pixels,
                     int             pitch)
```

Basically, what I want to do in my application is to read a single pixel from the window screen and detect if it's a transparent pixel or not.
How can I use that function?
What is the pitch attribute, how I define the SDL_Rect and how I get the pixel with the correct format? 
I'm detecting the mouse left click event and passing the x and y coordinates to a method as you can see:

```
void detectElementOnXandY(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y){

 // x represents the coordinate x.
 // y represents the coordinate y.

 // Here i have to call the function
 int result = SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, rect, format, pixels, pitch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pitch seems to be the length of a scanline in bytes. So depending of the format of your texture : 1 * bytesPerPixel. (probably 4 bytes per pixel)
The rect should be something like (x,y,x+1,y+1)
and the format should be something like SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888 or the equivalent for your particular texture.
You may have to inverse the y coordinate depending if SDL uses the OpenGL(bottom to top) convention or the Windows(top to bottom) convention.